# Multiple instances of a script running simultaneously in PHP?

Tags: php

Using the error log in PHP to debug code I came across the following situation which looks as if two instances of the same script are running in parallel. I'm sceptic about that, so I'm requesting your support to help me figure out what is going on.**EDIT**: The following occurs in a development server that serves a single user.

### **Code**

Following is an extract of the code running in my index.php script (which I have simplified since it's longer). The key is that I'm initiating a session and then redirecting. The lines strarting with /**/ are the lines I added to add data to the error log:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['check']))      //session initialization code
{
/*1*/static $thread = 0;
/*2*/error_log("\nInit block - Run: " . $thread++);
/*3*/error_log("\nInto init block - URI: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "Time: " . microtime());

$_SESSION['check'] = true;
/*4*/error_log("\nInit block - Run: " . $thread++);     /*execution of second script instance seems to start at this point*/

$_SESSION['var1'] = /*var1 initialization code*/;
/*5*/error_log("\nInit block - Run: " . $thread);

$_SESSION['var2'] = /*var 2 initialization code*/;
/*6*/error_log("\nInit block - Run: " . $thread);

$_SESSION['var3'] = /*var3 initialization code*/;
/*7*/error_log("\nInit block - Run: " . $thread);

$_SESSION['var4'] = /*var4 intialization code*/
/*8*/error_log("\nInit block - Run: " . $thread);

$_SESSION['var5'] = /*var5 initialization code*/
/*9*/error_log("\nInit block - Run: " . $thread++);
}

if(/*condition1*/)
{
/*10*/static $filter = 0;
/*11*/error_log("\nInto condition 1 - URI: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "Time: " . microtime());
/*12*/error_log("\nCondition 1 - Run: " . $filter);

header("Location: " . $targetUrl . $resultPage);    //Post->Redirect->Get
exit();
}
else
{
/*...*/
}
```

### **Error log output**

The output in the error log is as follows: I'm appending the code line that generated the output to make it less cumbersome to read, hopefully:

```
[05-Apr-2017 19:17:25] 
Init block - Run: 0     /*2*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:25] 
Into init block - URI: / Time: 0.59423800 1491430645 /*3*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:25] 
Init block - Run: 1     /*4*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:25] 
Init block - Run: 0     /*2*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:25] 
Into init block - URI: / Time: 0.70579800 1491430645 /*3*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:25] /*4*/
Init block - Run: 1

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*5*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*6*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*7*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*8*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*9*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Into condition 1 - URI: / Time: 0.94149400 1491430648   /*11*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Condition 1 - Run: 0    /*12*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*5*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:28] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*6*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:29] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*7*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:29] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*8*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:29] 
Init block - Run: 2     /*9*/

[05-Apr-2017 19:17:29] 
Into condition 1 - URI: / Time: 0.09837300 1491430649   /*11*/
```

As you can see, the code executes until line /*4*/, when it seems to get interrupted by a new instance of the script, and resumes only after the new instance ends execution. I was suspicious about the header function call, but the flow gets disrupted way before that point. In trying to find an answer I saw that logging can get duplicated depending on Apache's settings, but as you can see, this is not a case of double logging. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Same php script can run in parallel in multiple threads/processes in the server. So what you described above seems to be valid. Unless requests you're making are from the same user/session and default (file) session handler is used. In that case execution will block and scripts will be executed sequentially.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I forgot to add to my question precisely that point: The requests are from the same user and session, using the default session handler.

Comment: I believe it is imposible to run more than 1 instance of the same script...

Comment: @user3783407 can you confirm that single session is used? Sessions by default are stored in /var/lib/php/sessions. If you clear that folder in dev environment and run 2 instances of your script, can you see just one file created in that folder?

Comment: Thank you Max, I ran the test you proposed. If I open 2 instances of the script in the same browser (2 tabs in chrome) I see that a single session file is created. If I open 2 instances in 2 browsers (chrome + edge), 2 session files are created. As an additional clarification, the issue described above occured in both browsers separately while running a single instance in each. Does this help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if you ran your script in 2 different browsers it resulted in 2 sessions being created. Which means requests could work in parallel. Which explains mixing in error log you see.

Comment: Yes, but what you see above happens while running a single instance of the script in a single browser. I can guarantee that there are no other instances or sessions running at the same time.